# Как записать часть кода, используя функцию enumerate?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
def distance(num, blueprint):
step = None

for i in range(num):
    if blueprint[i] == 0:
        step = 0
    elif step is not None:
        step +=1
        blueprint[i] = step
    else:
        blueprint[i] = float('inf')

for i in range(num)[::-1]:
    if blueprint[i] == 0:
        step = 0
    else:
        step +=1
        blueprint[i] = min(blueprint[i], step)

return blueprint

if __name__ == '__main__':
    num = int(input())
    blueprint= list(map(int, input().split()))
    print(*distance(num, blueprint))
```

нужно записать часть кода, используя функцию enumerate

```
for i in range(num):
    if blueprint[i] == 0:
        step = 0
    elif step is not None:
        step +=1
        blueprint[i] = step
    else:
        blueprint[i] = float('inf')
```

Answer (score 0):

Предпологая, что `num == len(blueprint)`, вместо

```
for i in range(num):
    if blueprint[i] == 0:
        step = 0
```

примените

```
for i, bl in enumerate(blueprint):
    if bl == 0:
        step = 0
```

Но в вашем частном случае никакого преимущества в применении функции `enumerate()` я не вижу, т.к в этом цикле вы всё равно вынужден обращаетесь  прямо к элементам списка `blueprint`, чтобы изменить их значение.